# unterminated address regex while using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am using the below command but while running the command in linux, getting the below error.

```
sed -n '/^[2015/01/01 03:46/,/^[2015/01/01 03:47/p' < Input.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unterminated address regex
```

KIndly help me on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to escape the `[`, or else it thinks its start of a group, and escape to `/` in your data.

```
sed -n '/^\[2015\/01\/01 03:46/,/^\[2015\/01\/01 03:47/p' Input.txt
```

or (thanks to nu11p01n73R)

```
sed -n '\|^\[2015/01/01 03:46|,\|^\[2015/01/01 03:47|p' Input.txt
```

Comment: `[` starts a character class, not a group.

Answer (score 3):

escape `[` i.e. `\[` and change sed's delimiter to `#` or some character other than `/` so it will avoid you having to escape every `/`

```
sed -n '\#^\[2015/01/01 03:46#,\#^\[2015/01/01 03:47#p'
```

Note: I escape the first octothorpe in front of each pattern so that sed can interpret it as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

"[" is a special character in regex. You would need to escape it and use it like:

```
sed -n '/^\[2015\/01\/01 03:46/,/^\[2015\/01\/01 03:47/p' Input.txt
Output:
[2015/01/01 03:46] INFO ....
[2015/01/01 03:46] ERROR ....
[2015/01/01 03:47] INFO ....
```

Comment: This now looks like mine solution :)

Comment: Yeah tested by escaping slash and entered without escaping slash!