# Appending to file, sed unterminated address regex

Tags: regex, linux, sed, redhat

I'm trying to append to the end of a file, using the style from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26639/179769) but I get the error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated address regex

the command (I've also tried without the `-i` and same error):

```
sed -i -e '\$ahaha_value=26' example.txt
```

where I'm expecting `$` to get the end of the file and `a` to append.

I've looked at these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729772/unterminated-address-regex-while-using-sed), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772457/sed-e-expression-1-char-16-unterminated-address-regex), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234430/sed-unterminated-address-regex). The issues there seem to be regex based and I don't see the issue with my regex.

Comment: any particular reason to use sed? why not simply use `echo 'haha_value=26' >> example.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single quotes you don't need to escape `$` sign since it's not going to be evaluated by shell.

Either

```
 sed -e '$a...'
```

or

```
sed -e "\$a..."
```

Comment: just fyi I found out you do need the `-i` to actually edit the file but your answers worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i '' '$a\
haha_value=26
' example.txt
```