# How to escape certain characters for sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to remove a line from a file and understand this can be done with sed.

The command below fails because of **unterminated address regex**

```
sed -i '/$settings['file_temp_path'] = '../tmp';/d' file.php
```

Having read the the answer at [unterminated address regex while using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729772/unterminated-address-regex-while-using-sed) . I now understand this is because characters [ and / must be escaped.

Having tried this, the code below is still unsuccessful

```
sed -i '/$settings\['file_temp_path'] = '..\/tmp';/d' file.php
```

What is wrong with this? What am I missing?

Comment: What does the line you want to remove look like?

Comment: $settings['file_temp_path'] = '../tmp';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape several special characters in your pattern, including `$`.

Example content of `file.php`:

```
foo
$settings['file_temp_path'] = '../tmp';
bar
```

Example code:

```
$ sed -i "s/\$settings\['file_temp_path'\] = '..\/tmp';//" file.php                                                                        
$ cat file.php
foo

bar
```

Comment: Thank you. I find this prints the whole file, and I do see the correct line has been removed, and an empty line space remains. But when viewing the content of the file, I find the line is still present. Is another step necessary to save the changes?

Comment: So a number of additions were needed. Everything except the file name was enclosed in " ", then $, [, ], and / had to be escaped with /.

Comment: What is the purpose of s/ at the beginning and // at the end?

Comment: It's just `sed` syntax for substitution. You shouldn't have needed to make any changes to my code

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '\#\$settings\['\''file_temp_path'\''\] = '\''\.\./tmp'\'';#d' file
```

When the regexp/replacement contains the match delimiter (usually `/`), it can either be escaped/quoted or the delimiters can be altered i.e. `/\/tmp/` or `\#/tmp#`. Note that in the case of the substitution command `s/\/tmp/replacement/` can also be `s#/tmp#replacement#` and leading delimiter does not need to escaped/quoted.

Meta characters i.e. `^`,`$`,`[`,`]`,`*`,`.`,`\` and `&` must be escaped/quoted by `\`or placed in a character class e.g. `.` should be `\.` or `[.]`.

As a rule of thumb, sed commands should be enclosed in single quotes `'` and for single quotes to be included in the regexp they should be replaced by `'\''` which closes off the existing commands, shell escapes/quotes a `'` and reopens the next sed command.

Using double quotes `"` may also be used but may have unexpected side effects as they are open to shell interpolation.

N.B. If the regexp/substitution delimiter is put inside a character class it does not need to be escaped/quoted i.e. if `/` is the delimiter then `[/]` is the same as `\/`. Also note, that `{`,`}`,`|`,`?` and `+` should not be escaped/quoted if they are to represent their literal value unless the `-E` or `-r` sed command line option is invoked, in which case they should be i.e `+` represents the plus sign as does `\+` when the `-E` is invoked, whereas `\+` and `+` when the `-E` or `-r` is invoked represent one or more of the preceding character/group.